# I get nullsafety error when I try to add firebase package to pubsec.yaml file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add `Firebase` to my `Flutter App` named `biletsatis` .

But when I try pub get, I get this error.

```
[biletsatis] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in biletsatis...
Resolving dependencies...
Because firebase_core >=0.7.0 <0.8.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^3.0.1 and cloud_firestore >=4.3.2 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.5.3, firebase_core >=0.7.0 <0.8.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore >=4.3.2.
So, because biletsatis depends on both cloud_firestore ^4.4.3 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "C:\Users\USER\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\Users\USER\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 1

exit code 1
```

Here is my `dependencies` section in `pubsec.yaml` file

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  flutter_form_bloc: ^0.30.1

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.3
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
```

Comment: Why are you constraining firebase_core to 0.x.x when the current latest is 2.7.0? Instead, set it to `any` and see what gets resolved, or look up the version number in pub.dev

Comment: I also used 2.7.0. but using any resolved the problem. Thanks a lot. But what was the cause of problem can you spot it?

Comment: The error message tells you all you need to know - you had incompatible versions. firebase_core >=0.7.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^3.0.1 BUT cloud_firestore >=4.3.2 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.5.3. So you have one dependency needs core v3 and one needs core v4 - hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

All of the dependencies in your Flutter project are updated to the most recent major versions using this command.